# Connecting to Unity 3d tcp server from mac

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, unity-game-engine

I have a TCP server inside Unity 3D app. I want to connect to it from macbook. This is the Unity code in C#.

```
listener = new TcpListener(port);   

// start listening
listener.Start();

// wait for our first client
listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(OnAcceptTcpClientComplete, this);
```

Now, I want to connect from mac terminal over WiFi. I compiled the app into both Android and iOS apps. For Android, I have given a permission in manifest file -  .

But, for iOS, I am unable to connect or telnet to iPhone or iPad. Is there any permission required? Am I missing something for iOS?

***Note:** My app for iOS compiles well, installs correctly on the device as well. No errors in xCode console. I am also able to telnet from the device itself, but unable to telnet from outside.*

Comment: Yes I did! :)https://github.com/imkira/mobiledevice